# Carry/Copy NaN value to another column DF Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the a df which looks like this:

```
|  id | qty  | item |
+-----+------+------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 |
| 002 |  500 | NaN  |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 |
```

I want to copy the NaN values from `df['item']` to `df['qty']`, so that it looks this :

```
|  id | qty  |   item   |
+-----+------+----------+
| 001 |  700 | CB04 box |
| 002 |  NaN | NaN      |
| 003 | 1500 | AB01 box |
```

i did the following

```
df['qty'] = df.loc[df['item'].isnull(),'item']
```

but my df turned out to be like this.

```
|  id | qty |   item   |
+-----+-----+----------+
| 001 | NaN | CB04 box |
| 002 | NaN | NaN      |
| 003 | NaN | AB01 box |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach isn't working because you are selecting the column **`item`**, when it is null, and setting **`qty`** equal to that result, which is always `NaN`, so it fills **`qty`** with `NaN`

Use **`loc`** with boolean indexing and set your desired column.  You were close, just not assigning quite right.

```
df.loc[df.item.isnull(), 'qty'] = np.nan

   id     qty  item
0   1   700.0  CB04
1   2     NaN   NaN
2   3  1500.0  AB01
```

Also using **`np.where`** (slightly faster when I tested on a 300k row dataframe)

```
df.qty = np.where(df.item.isnull(), np.nan, df.qty)
```